In Ansible, how can I handle variables when an IP address is used when running a playbook?
I have an inventories/path/hosts.yml file that has something like this, for example.
all:
  children:
    host1:
      hosts:
        10.10.10.1
    host2:
      hosts:
        10.10.10.2

Then I set this up in group_vars to set the credentials for each host.
group_vars/host1.yml
--------------------
ansible_user: admin
ansible_password: password1

group_vars/host2.yml
--------------------
ansible_user: admin
ansible_password: password2

This all works if the user runs ansible-playbook using the host name, that is, the credentials in their respective group_vars get picked up.
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/path/hosts.yml -e var_host=host1 my_playbook.yml

How can I set this up so the respective credentials are picked up when the user passes the IP address of the host instead of label?
$ ansible-playbook -i 10.10.10.1, -e var_host=10.10.10.1 my_playbook.yml


The inventory posted in the question seems to be invalid (on 2.9 at least, which I have). Also as per documentation.

@seshadri_c regardless, how can I make it work with IP addresses?

The way host1 and host2 are defined in your inventory, they are not hosts. They are group names. Hosts are defined under a group with hosts: directive. Host specific variables are picked up from host_vars/. Unfortunately your question is not reproducible, so this is my observation.

after creating some inventory, group_vars, host_vars it is good to check it out issuing: ansible-inventory all --graph --vars (instead of 'all' we can use a different group from inventory).
